# "Discrete" analogue of cross-partial derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Take a function $\Phi(x,y): \mathbb{R}^K\times \mathbb{R}^K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Here the arguments of $\Phi$ are two $K\times 1$ vectors, $x$ and $y$.

Consider the cross-partial derivative of $\Phi(x,y)$ with respect $x$ and $y$ and evaluate it at $(x,y)=(a,b)$ (assume that such derivative exists). We denote it by
$$
\frac{\partial \Phi(a,b)}{\partial x \partial y}
$$

I'm looking for the analogue of this derivative when $x$ and $y$ can only take integer values.

My hypothesis is that the analogue of the derivative above could be
$$
[1] \hspace{1cm}\frac{\partial \Phi(a,b)}{\partial x \partial y} \approx \Phi(a+1,b+1)+\Phi(a,b)-\Phi(a+1,b)-\Phi(a,b+1)
$$
Is this correct?

Also, what would be the interpretation of the result? I.e., suppose that algebraic sum gives me a positive value: what does that mean?

---

Following a comment below, the concept of finite differences [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Multivariate_finite_differences) is helpful. In particular
$$
[2] \hspace{1cm} \frac{\partial \Phi(a,b)}{\partial x \partial y} \approx \frac{\Phi(a+1,b+1)+\Phi(a-1,b-1)-\Phi(a-1,b+1)-\Phi(a+1,b-1)}{4}
$$

I this correct? I am particularly interested in the sign of the numerator. Could you help me to interpret this sign?

Comment: The idea you are looking for is called a *finite difference*; the wikipedia page is a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make my comment more precise, the expression you have wrote above would be the multivariable forward finite difference.

As for interpretation, I guess you could just say that it's an approximation of the ordinary derivative of $\Phi$ at $(a,b)$ if $\Phi$ were defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$; you can't say much more about the accuracy about the approximation unless you know more about $\Phi$. It might help if you give more context for the problem.

Comment: Thanks. What is the correct approximation: [1] or [2] (see my question)? Also, your interpretation seems to suggest that $\Phi(a+1,b+1)=\Phi(a,b)+\frac{\partial \Phi(a,b)}{\partial x \partial y}$ which is not the case.

Comment: I think in [1] I use the concept of "forward difference", while in [2] Wikipedia uses the concept of "central difference", but I'm not sure. Could you clarify?

Comment: Yes, [1] is the forward difference while [2] is the central difference. Neither one is more "correct" than the other until you start to specify what you mean by "correct"; it depends on what exactly you want the finite difference to approximate, which depends on the context of what exactly $\Phi$ is here and why you're taking derivatives of it. Also you are correct in pointing out that my interpretation is incorrect; I'll correct it momentarily.

Comment: Thanks. Could you just help me to interpret the numerator of [1]? That is what I care the most.

Comment: As I said, there's not much to say unless you can provide more context. The only things you could say would come from rearranging the terms of [1].

Comment: Thanks. Can I  ask you what does it mean if the classical cross-derivative is positive? I suppose that should be also the interpretation of the sign of the numerator of [1].

Comment: Suppose $f(x,y)$ is differentiable and $\partial f(a,b)/\partial x\partial y>0$. Then this means that $\partial f(a,b)/\partial x$ has positive slope in $y$, or that $\partial f(a,b)/\partial y$ has positive slope in $x$. There is a more sophisticated geometric answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1312297/geometric-meaning-of-cross-partial-derivative).